# Does publishing research in physics during bachelor degree help in applying for master’s in mathematics?

Tags: masters, mathematics, funding, physics, changing-fields

Before I applied for my bachelor degree, I was unsure whether to take physics or mathematics because I liked both of them equally. Then I decided to go for a mathematics degree. Currently I am in the last year of that degree. During my time at university I published several research papers in theoretical physics in top journals in the field and I got several awards from my university. Also, in my mathematics degree, I have so far achieved the highest marks in my mathematics department. I have three months to graduate and I am looking to start a master’s degree.

I am an international student (outside Europe and America), and I am looking to continue my study in Europe, but there are several things that I am unsure about and I would appreciate some help on:

1. Does publishing research papers in physics help me get a scholarship for a master’s in mathematics in Europe or is it irrelevant?
2. Does publishing research papers in physics help me get a scholarship for a master’s in physics in Europe even though I have bachelor in Mathematics?

Comment: It'd be great if someone could answer this question. I have a similar concern.

Comment: @JunaidAftab - If this is important to you, consider starting a bounty on this question (see link right under the comments).

Comment: @JunaidAftab does my answer help your situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a very strong case for either choice, I am not familiar with the regulations in Europe, but can give a general perspective.

Consider, you have:

- what appears to be a very strong publication history in the theoretical physics field
- a very strong academic record (including awards) for mathematics.

On face value, you have clearly demonstrated your capacity to publish research in top journals, you have demonstrable knowledge of the subject areas and you have shown initiative.

Given that a lot of physics has a significant complex mathematical content (and both form part of the broader 'STEM' fields), then there are 'demonstrable transferable skills' that can crossover between the two disciplines. In that regard, as an example, I originally studied geology, particularly geophysics - the demonstrable analytical and data modelling skills helped me to get into the Masters (and eventually the PhD) in physics.

Asking the admissions people in the desired universities about the specific requirements would help clarify this.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to both of your questions is "yes".  Indeed, publishing original research in any STEM field has at least some (and usually quite a substantial) positive impact on graduate school applications for programs in other STEM fields.